# Querying between two dates returns incorrect results in MongoDB?

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose

NOTE: I'm only encountering this in production, after importing the collection I exported from my local environment.

So, in production, when I run this in Robo 3T:

`db.getCollection('...').find({created_at: {$gte: new Date(2020, 7, 19), $lt: new Date(2020, 7, 20)}})`

It gives me the correct results:

`{ created_at: 2020-08-18 22:00:46.244Z }, { created_at: 2020-08-18 22:11:25.135Z }, { created_at: 2020-08-18 22:19:27.921Z }, { created_at: 2020-08-19 08:56:44.534Z }`.

I store the date like this in the model, using the `Date` type:

```
....
created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
```

I have two Material date pickers in my UI. On page load, the records created today are fetched (08/19/2020).

**my.component.ts**

```
const fromDate = new Date();
    const toDate = new Date();
    const filter = {
      dates: {
        from: {
          year: fromDate.getFullYear(), // 2020
          month: fromDate.getMonth(), // 7
          day: fromDate.getDate() // 19
        },
        to: {
          year: toDate.getFullYear(), // 2020
          month: toDate.getMonth(), // 7
          day: toDate.getDate() // 19
        }
      }
    };
```

Then I send the `filter` object to the API.

```
if (req.body.filters.dates) {
                            let fromDate = req.body.filters.dates.from;
                            let toDate = req.body.filters.dates.to;
                            dateFilters = {created_at: {
                                    "$gte": new Date(fromDate.year, fromDate.month, fromDate.day),
                                    "$lt": new Date(toDate.year, toDate.month, (toDate.day + 1))
                                }
                            };
                        }

                        MyModel.find(dateFilters, function(err, results) {
                            if (err) {
                                return next(err);
                            } else if (results) {
                                if (results.length) {
                                    return res.status(200).json({
                                        data: results
                                    });
                                } ...
                            }
                        });
```

But the API only returns one record for today instead of 4, the last one I mentioned above, `{ created_at: 2020-08-19 08:56:44.534Z }`. If I select 8/18/2020 - 8/18/2020, then it returns the other 3 records. If I select 8/18/2020 - 8/19/2020, it returns all 4.

First 3 records were created in my local environment, 4th one was created in production. Our production server is in (GMT-7), if that helps.

Comment: You sure they are *correct* in the first place? For example, this thing is returned `created_at: 2020-08-18 22:00:46.244Z` when you expect `created_at` to be `gte new Date(2020, 7, 19)` which I believe is `2020-07-19 00:00:00.000Z`, and `lt new Date(2020, 7, 20)` which is `2020-07-20 00:00:00.000Z` right? Or am I missing something here? Months are indexed from 0?

Comment: Hi @MarekPiotrowski yes, months are indexed from 0 for `Date.prototype.getMonth()`, and when you do `new Date('2020-08-18 22:00:46.244Z')` it actually returns August 19, 2020. In my local environment, I log the `dateFilters`, and this is what I get: `{ '$gte': 2020-08-18T16:00:00.000Z,
     '$lt': 2020-08-19T16:00:00.000Z }` - the dates are already in ISO format